# Add {_UIVersionString} into information management policy setting via powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, information-policy

is it possible to set the label {_UIVersionString} into information management policy setting via powershell

Thanks!

Viktor

Answer (score 0):

Configuring default Office 365 Labels using PowerShell for your reference:

http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2018/05/configuring-default-office-365-labels-using-powershell/

Comment: Thanks Lisa, I'll try.

Comment: @lisa Please don't add just a link, it may be not available in the future, so please add more details on your answer, then add the link as a reference! Thanks